# Regex to get a specific function code from php file

Tags: php, regex

I'm editing a PHP file to replace a function's code by another code provided.
My problem is that the function's code may change. So, I don't know exactly how I should do the regex to find it.

Here's an example:

```
function lol()
{
    echo('omg');
    $num=0;
    while($num<100)
    {
        echo('ok');
    }
}
function teste()
{
    echo('ola');
    while($num<100)
    {
        echo('ok');
    }
}
function test()
{
    echo('oi');
    while($num<100)
    {
        echo('ok');
    }
}
```

What I need is to get the code of function teste(), which would be:

```
echo('ola');
while($num<100)
{
    echo('ok');
}
```

BUT: I do not know how many whiles, foreaches or how many brackets are inside the functions, neither I don't know it's order. The example was just an example.

How would I be able to get the function's code?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your final goal with this? There may be a better way of doing what you want

Comment: I wouldn't even try to parse PHP with regex.

Comment: do you need EVERYTHING is inside the function teste() or just the first line?

Comment: That's not the code for function `teste`

Comment: Do you want the full content of your function of just the echo?

Comment: Hello, I would need everything. Sorry, my example is not correct I will correct it.

Comment: @user2271353 you want only the function `teste` or all the functions in an array ?

Comment: The example has already been corrected. I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @HamZa, I only want the function teste

Comment: Pekka, replace the function teste's code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Disclaimer

As other users stated, this is probably not a good approach. And if you decided to use it anyway, **double-check your result** as `regex` can be treacherous.

### Ugly solution

You can you something like to match even if the function is the last one (@Nippey):

```
(?:function teste\(\))[^{]*{(.*?)}[^}]*?(?:function|\Z)
```

`Note:` I'm using `(?:xyz)` which is for [non-capturing parentheses group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html). Check if your regex engine support it.

#### Output

```
    echo('ola');
    while($num<100)
    {
        echo('ok');
    }
```

Comment: I know you explicitly stated that this works if `teste` is not the last function... but what happens if it is?

Comment: You could use this modification, so you don't have to remove the brackets: `(?:function teste\(\))[^{]*{(.*?)}[^}]*?(?:function)`

Comment: @STTLCU: Use this: `(?:function teste\(\))[^{]*{(.*?)}[^}]*?(?:function|\Z)`

Comment: @EdouardLopez i'm not OP but i guess that if you used nippey's suggestion now the output is without external braces

Comment: I used the first option, where function is not the last function, as I know it isn't and won't be in the platform which with I'm working for. However, this last one is better, so thank you both of you :)

Answer (score 1):

Using recursive pattern `(?R)` you can match nested brackets:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('#(.*?)\{((?:[^{}]|(?R))*)\}|.*#si', function($m){
    if(isset($m[1], $m[2]) && preg_match('#function\s+teste\b#i', $m[1])){
        return $m[2];
    }
}, $code); // Anonymous function is used here which means PHP 5.3 is required

echo $result;
```

[**Online demo**](http://ideone.com/7ifEtz)